# Iterate over Ruby FFI Struct layout

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

I am using the really awesome [ruby ffi](http://github.com/ffi/ffi) library to access functions in a c library in ruby.

Is there a way to iterate over the layout of a Ruby FFI::Struct?

example FFI::Struct:

```
class Example < FFI::Struct
  layout :name, string,
         :desc, :string,
         :type, :int,
         :value, :string
end
```

this doesn't seem to work but something like the below pseudo code:

```
example_struct.each_key do |key|
  puts key
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source for struct.rb](http://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/de8f031d4a410251ed2f7d8de02103e5012d761a/lib/ffi/struct.rb), I found that you can call `Struct::members` to get an array of the symbols you've defined as "keys".

From there, you've also got `Struct::values` for the values of each member, `Struct::offsets` for the offsets of each member, and a few other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a bit more expensive than iterating through the Struct's members, but you can also convert it to a hash with `to_h`.

```
Foo = Struct.new(:a, :b, :c)
=> Foo
baz = Foo.new(1,2,3)
=> #<struct Foo a=1, b=2, c=3>
baz.to_h
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```